# after using CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA custom tag's content still not visible

Tags: html, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

I have this scenario: there are three modules, header.module, _shared.module and app.module. 
`header.module` imports and exports the header component. `_shared.module` acts as a wrapper module and imports the `header.module`. `app.module` finally imports the `_shared.module`.
Finally i am using the header through it's selector eg `<dir-header>` in app.component.html. I have even included CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in app.module to suppress any error that may arise. But i'm no longer able to see the header, although the tag `<dir-header></dir-header>` is there in DOM, but it's content `<div class="..." >...</div>` is not.

`header.module` :-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { HeaderRoutingModule } from './header-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [HeaderRoutingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent
    ]
})

export class HeaderModule {}
```

`_shared.module` :-

```
import { HeaderModule } from './header/header.module';
import { FooterModule } from './footer/footer.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HeaderModule,
        FooterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

`app.module` :-

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
/*rest of the code*/
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  imports: 
    [...
       SharedModule,
    ...
    ],
  providers: [CrudService, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**EDIT**: It is not importing the `<header-dir>` from `header.module` rather creating a new custom selector in `app.component.html`. How do I import the header from `header.module` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ISSUE SOLVED] first of all, remove the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA from `app.module` because it is not really required in THIS case. Next, in `_shared.module` under the `exports` section, also export the custom modules you have imported here i.e. `header.module` and `foot.module` :-

`_shared.module`

```
import { NgModule}       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderModule } from './header/header.module';
import { FooterModule } from './footer/footer.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HeaderModule,
        FooterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [HeaderModule,
        FooterModule]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```